# Using jQuery to close alert, get alert's text

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, alert

I am working on a Java project and I need to use jQuery (it is my task). Now I need to handle an alert and verify that the message I need is displayed. I dug up a bunch of information, but all of it is about creating alerts and etc.

[image]

Could someone explain it to me how it works and how I need to use it? Maybe it is impossible? I am using jQuery in my task.

At this time I have this code and I need to add functionality described above.

```java
public void getCoordinates() {
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

    js.executeScript("var position = $('.flash').position();" +
    "$('#top').val(Math.round(position.top));" +
    "$('#left').val(Math.round(position.left));" +
    "$('#process').click();");
}
```

Comment: I mean that i need to do all of this using jQuery.

Comment: do you want to alert the user with default alert or you are trying to create  custom alert

Comment: @AtalShrivastava i already have an alert, i didn`t create it, it already was on the site, after some steps, it shows up, i just need to get text from it and close it (by clicking on "OK")

Comment: jQuery UI has a [dialog widget](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/), but it's probably easier to use [JavaScript's implemented `alert()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/API/Window/alert).

Comment: @GanshinaNastya Can you please attach a screenshot of the alert if possible? Because the solution may be vary based on the type of alert.

Comment: You should add the java tag to your question. java !== javascript

Comment: @JuhilKamothi check pls